# Conditional NOT NULL case SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, null, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to calculate a field and I want it to behave differently depending on if one of the columns happens to be null. I am using MySQL

```
CASE 
  WHEN reply.replies <> NULL THEN
  24/((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(qcr.LAST_MOD_TIME)+3600)/3600)*(ces.EXPERT_SCORE+2.5*scs.SIMILARITY)*(EXP(-reply.replies))
  ELSE 1
END as ANSWER_SCORE
```

Is this the right syntax?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to have `when reply.replies IS NOT NULL`

NULL is a special case in SQL and cannot be compared with = or <> operators. IS NULL and IS NOT NULL are used instead.

Comment: Sure it can be compared using `=`, `<` and `<>`. The result of the comparison is `NULL`. Agree that three-valued boolean logic is not for everybody, but you can't say 'it cannot be compared'.

Comment: while this shows how to use CASE, the code in question doesn't even need a case

Answer (score 6):

```
case when reply.replies IS NOT NULL ...
```

You can't compare NULL with the regular (arithmetic) comparison operators. Any arithmetic comparison to NULL will return NULL, even `NULL = NULL` or `NULL <> NULL` will yield NULL.

Use `IS` or `IS NOT` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a case statement for this.
Use the [IFNULL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
IFNULL(24/((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(qcr.LAST_MOD_TIME)+3600)/3600)
*(ces.EXPERT_SCORE+2.5*scs.SIMILARITY)*(EXP(-reply.replies)), 1) as ANSWER_SCORE
```

If reply.replies is null, the expression is shortcut to NULL
IFNULL then takes the 2nd parameter (1) and gives that as a result when it happens.

For other cases where you do need to compare to NULL, [this will help you](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) to work with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a CASE Statement Checking Null

```
SELECT MAX(id+1),  
IF(MAX(id+1) IS NULL, 1, MAX(id+1))
AS id   
FROM `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be best if you used is not null in SQL syntax, the '<>' is means the column has value to compare with other sentences.