# SELECT one column if the other is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select `a2.date` if it's there, but if it's `NULL` I want to select `a1.date` (`a2` is being left-joined). This:

```
SELECT a2.date OR a1.date
       ...
```

Simply returns a boolean result (as one would expect), how do I get the actual value of the non-null column though? (`a2.date` is preferred, but if it's null then `a1.date`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional NOT NULL case SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821031/conditional-not-null-case-sql)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The ANSI means is to use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(a2.date, a1.date) AS `date`
   ...
```

The MySQL native syntax is [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT IFNULL(a2.date, a1.date) AS `date`
   ...
```

Unlike COALESCE, IFNULL is not portable to other databases.

Another ANSI syntax, the [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html), is an option:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN a2.date IS NULL THEN a1.date
         ELSE a2.date
       END AS `date`
   ...
```

It requires more direction to work properly, but is more flexible if requirements change.

Comment: `COALESCE` is syntactic sugar for the equivalent `CASE` statement so it is kind of redundant to mention it here. To use an analogy, all SQL constraints can be expressed using a `SELECT COUNT(*)` (cardinality) query but if I pointed this out in every answer I posted that used a `FOREIGN KEY` it might become warying for all concerned. But a downvote for that would be a little harsh.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Don't worry about the downvoters - or, in more current terms, "haters gonna hate."

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`CASE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) for the select.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a2.date IS NULL THEN a1.date
    ELSE a2.date END AS mydate
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the COALESCE function.

Takes a variable number of arguments and returns the first non-null one. It works fine with joins.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COALESCE(a2.date, a1.date) ...
```