# MYSQL Case in select statement for checking null

Tags: mysql, sql

in MySQL query if I pass:

```
  case guides.Gud_Publish_Date 
     when null then "Unscheduled" 
     else "Forth Coming Titles" 
  end
```

then it is considering all is null even the Gud_Publish_Date has value also. the full SQL statement is

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , (
        CASE guides.Gud_Publish_Date
            WHEN NULL
                THEN "Unscheduled"
            ELSE "Forth Coming Titles"
            END
        ) AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

Comment: Trivial, but I believe forthcoming is one word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional NOT NULL case SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821031/conditional-not-null-case-sql)

Answer (score 89):

try using `IF`

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , IF(guides.Gud_Publish_Date IS NULL,'Unscheduled','Forth Coming Titles') 
             AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

or if you really want `CASE`

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , (
        CASE 
            WHEN guides.Gud_Publish_Date IS NULL
            THEN 'Unscheduled'
            ELSE 'Forth Coming Titles'
        END
      ) AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

Comment: showing error
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'guides.Gud_Publish_Date IS NULL,"Unscheduled","Forth Coming Titles") as Schedule' at line 3 */

However the Case statement is working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you really using `mysql`? :D because the codes I supplied are all working.

Answer (score 15):

I found this -a couple of months- old post. Using `COALESCE` option as intended by Rajan, you can do,

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , CASE COALESCE(guides.Gud_Publish_Date, 0)
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Unscheduled'
                 ELSE 'Forth Coming Titles'
          END  AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

The code above assumes that `guides.Gud_Publish_Date` cannot take the value 0, which I can do because it is a date. If that weren't the case you can change 0 for another value that it cannot take; maybe your favorite float like `3.1415` or a null identifier `'null'`.

Comment: This adds an implicit assumption to your code, namely that some column will never take the value 0 (or 3.1415 or 'null' or whatever). Avoid implicit assumptions ... they are easily forgotten and thus easily violated.

Comment: Thanks! I needed a solution that worked in MySQL and SQLite and this fits the bill because IF doesn't exist in SQLite.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , (
        CASE WHEN guides.Gud_Publish_Date IS NULL
            THEN "Unscheduled"
            ELSE "Forth Coming Titles"
            END
        ) AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT guides.Gud_Id
    , guides.Gud_Image
    , guides.Gud_SubEditor
    , guides.Gud_Reprint_Status
    , guides.Gud_Publish_Date
    , guides.Gud_Img_Chk
    , guides.Gud_Published
    , guides.Gud_View
    , coalesce((
        CASE guides.Gud_Publish_Date
            WHEN NULL
                THEN 'Unscheduled'
            ELSE 'Forth Coming Titles'
            END
        ), 'Unscheduled') AS Schedules
FROM guides
```

Comment: This won't work.  When NULL, the CASE expression misses the entry and returns 'Forth Coming Titles'; since it is not NULL the COALESCE returns the same.